# std::list::sort and pointers to elements

Tags: c++, list, sorting, pointers, reference

Do Pointers which point to elements of a std::list remain valid if I call the sort() method over the list? Is there a guarantee for this (standard)? It seems to work under Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From "Working Draft C++, 2012-11-02"

> **23.3.5.5 list operations [list.ops]**
>   `void sort();`
>   `template <class Compare> void sort(Compare comp);`
>   28 Requires: `operator<` (for the first version) or comp (for the second version) shall define a strict weak
>         ordering (25.4).
>   **29 Effects: Sorts the list according to the `operator<` or a `Compare` function object. Does not affect the
>         validity of iterators and references.**
>   30 Remarks: Stable.
>   31 Complexity: Approximately N log(N ) comparisons, where `N == size()`.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting does not move elements of the list in the memory, only changes the next and previous link pointers. It should be fine.